# Create contact without user

Tags: liferay

I try to create a contact that is not associated to an user. All "real" users are imported from LDAP. I want to show a global contact list for different purposes like a birthday-list and a phone book. Not all entries in these lists are imported as users. Now I want to create these contacts with the ContactLocalServiceUtil class programmatically. Are there any advices how to do this? There is no method that needs neither a user-id nor a contact-id.

Answer (score 1):

A Contact, as contained in Liferay's API, is always the contact data of a user. Just because the name describes what you need, does not mean that the underlying concept matches as well. You probably need different data for a general purpose phone book anyways and it's probably easier to introduce your own contact class than adjusting the existing model (you can't add fields to API classes anyway - your only way of extending Liferay's ContactModel would be through Expando fields)

Therefor the advice is: Create your own contact class. If you want to react to user data changes when LDAP is updated, you'll need to frequently import the user data and for example create a model listener on Liferay's contact that updates your custom contacts whenever an update from LDAP is coming in.